# Add back in child theme what the parent theme removed with remove_action

Tags: functions, hooks, actions, child-theme

My parent theme removes the emoji fallback script that makes emoji show up as images:

```php
// parent theme's functions.php
remove_action('wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7);
remove_action('wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles');
```

I want to add it back in the child theme (to make this configuration survive theme updates) but if I just `add_action` it either doesn't work at all or works for the `wp-emoji.js` script but not for the CSS styles (`print_emoji_styles`) – emojis appear enormous, SVG spreads to all the available space.

If I disable the two lines in the parent theme everything works as expected.

What is going on, what should I look for to figure out the correct orchestration here?

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a higher priority for both the script AND the styles seems to work:

```php
add_action('wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 8);
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles', 8);
```